# hide / compile ssh key so it can't be used outside a public script

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting, scp

Does anybody have an idea how can I use an ssh private key in a script to scp some files from a server using a private key to connect but make sure the key can't be extracted to be used for something else?

The servers are already deployed and new users or new keys can't be generated.
I have the root key.  The script/ app should just grab a few files from a folder without exposing the key to the user.

Comment: If it is a *public* key it will not gain you access to the server. (not to mention *public* keys are posted publicly) The *private* key is the one you care about. If you have the private key for `root`, talk to the server admin and have him generate a new key that cannot be used successfully to gain access allowing `rm -r /` (even though you say you can't, it's worth doing in this case). Otherwise, you will be relying on Linux file permissions to allow the user to `x` execute the script without having `read` permissions in order to obscure the location of the key - not optimal at all.

Comment: No. What is the X problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is that I have a bunch of linux boxes deployed to customers.  They are not supposed to have root access so I can not give them the private key but everybody needs to copy some files from the system.   Can I encapsulate the key in an app or script that would copy the files without risking them to have access to the machine?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your ideas about public/private keys backwards.

If I give you my public key, then my private key allows me to access your computer. This effectively solves your problem, as you should never share your private key, and you'll append public keys to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server you want to access.

It sounds like you already have the private key to access the server, so no need to encrypt, as you use that to access the server not the other way around.

Use it `scp -i ...`

Hopefully helpful, here's a tutorial on setting up keys:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: The problem that I have is a little tricky :  I have to provide a script / app that can copy some specific files making use of the root private key without enabling the users to connect with the key on their own for other purposes.

Comment: The solution above would not work for me as it would expose the private key,

Comment: Why not give it a web facing api to allow for downloading the specific files you want users to have access to then? It's a much simpler solution.

Comment: I would but the software is already deployed on them. I can not add anything more on them ....

Comment: If you have the root key you should be able to do anything on the machine, such as add or remove files. This is why most of us are confused about your problem. You could possibly compile the key into your program, but that's only obscuring it, someone could technically figure it out by reverse engineering your software.

Comment: Yes.  I  do not have direct access to the systems and I can not add anything on them.  My task is to allow users to copy the files from a folder.  Any ideea where I could find an example of a script that compiles the key in the script itself?

Comment: You're going to want to write it in a compiled language such as c, c++, or Java Id Google from there.

Comment: Ok. starting the search for that . Thanks